# Add language to genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree

I followed the instructions for the `genealogytree` package to create a Hungarian language library.  I tested it but I now want to use the library.  What do I need to do? I have TeXLive on a Fedora Liux system. I have copied `gtrlang.hungarian.code.tex` to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/genealogytree` and ran `texhash` but I still get `Package genealogytree Error: The library 'lang.hungarian' is unknown.`.

Comment: It is rather hard to debug this. Did you try to put the library file in the same directory as the file which you are compiling?

Comment: Yes.  `genealogytree` cannot find it in the current (working) directory, and this is why I tried to put it in the `TeXLive` dist directory.  I ran `texhash` and I do see the file in the appropriate `ls-R` file, but the error persists.  Unfortunately, the docs of `genealogytree` don't give indication what to do.

Comment: Indeed. I tried to add a library and failed as well. In the code you find `\IfFileExists{gtrlib.\pgfkeyscurrentname.code.tex}%`, so there might be some confusion between `gtrlib` and `gtrlang` but just renaming the file accordingly does not fix the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't install into `/usr/share/texlive` regardless. That's for DNF to manage. Instead, use the value of `TEXMFLOCAL` (needs `texhash`) or `TEXMFHOME` (no need for `texhash`).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Does it work for, say, Danish? (I know I could test, but then I'd have to remember how to make a minimal example for the package.)

Comment: Have you tried adding `\makeatletter\gtr@add@library{lang.hungarian}{gtrlang.hungarian.code.tex}\makeatother` after loading the package and before setting the language, in the preamble?

Comment: @cfr I copied `cp /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/genealogytree/gtrlang.german.code.tex gtrlang.bavarian.code.tex` (of course in my local directory) and tried to load bavarian. Didn't work. `\makeatletter
\input{gtrlang.bavarian.code.tex}
\makeatother` does work, so I think it could be a bug.

Comment: @MátéWierdl What happens if you copy your language file to `gtrlib.lang.hungarian.code.tex`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I followed the instructions in `genealogytree-languages.pdf` for testing a new language with `bavarian` created as you described (I think) and the test document provided compiled fine (and includes output for `bavarian`). However, I'm not sure that custom languages can be used out-of-the-box in the same way as those provided by the package.

Comment: However, I'm not sure that's actually testing the same thing ... ?

Comment: I am not sure it's a bug @Schrödinger'scat. It seems to be broken by design ....

Comment: @cfr I'd like to encourage you to add an answer. There is a great demand for Welsh genealogy trees. ;-)

Comment: @cfr For me the following works: 1. in the same folder as the `.tex` file: `cp /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/genealogytree/gtrlang.german.code.tex gtrlib.lang.bavarian.code.tex`. 2. In `gtrlib.lang.bavarian.code.tex` replace `language@/german/.code` by `language@/bavarian/.code`. 3. put `\gtrset{language=bavarian}` in the preamble. Then it does translate e.g. dates to German/Bavarian.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I replaced all the `german`s, but I didn't use `gtrlib`. However, I don't understand why yours worked. Maybe it is a bug, then.

Comment: @cfr In your case the file name is `gtrlang.bavarian.code.tex` and it works?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The language test file compiles, yes. But that doesn't mean it works for real, no. It passes the packages test compilation. That's all.

Comment: @cfr In my case it does work, I think. At least it successfully replaced February by the Bavarian word Februar in a date.

Comment: Consider submitting a pull request to Thomas F. Sturm. I did so for Danish: https://github.com/T-F-S/genealogytree/pull/2